# Is hushmail a spam source?

Tags: email, spam

I am new so I don't know the history. But why, after I just found out, do all hushmail email users cannot register or log in to the website that I am administering.

Is hushmail a spam source? Or any giant bad guy is using hushmail serious enough to block all users who use hushmail?

Anyone knows about that?

http://www.hushmail.com/ looks fine to me

Comment: What register/login system does your website use? What CMS does it use (if any)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forum software such as [vbulletin](http://www.vbulletin.org/) offers modules such as ['undisposable'](http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=210946) that block users of free email services including hushmail, hotmail, and whatever domains you specify.

This is usually an attempt to reduce spam, because free and disposable email addresses are more likely to be used by spammers.

To lift these restrictions, you need to determine where in your forum/content management system they're being applied. You'll probably need the highest level admin access in order to change settings like these. If you edit your question to explain what software you're using and how much control you have over it, we may be able to find instructions to override the restrictions or whitelist hushmail accounts for you.